# Consequence of adding the same eventListener multiple times

Tags: actionscript-3

**Background:** I have a legacy project which I've been tasked with debugging and revising. The budget is very low and doesn't allow for significant refactoring. I am slowly working my way into the code and coming across many possible issues and/or inefficiencies.

**Question:** What are the consequences of adding the same eventListener multiple times? Does it overwrite the existing eventListener? Is this just a matter of inefficiency?

There is a routine which is called very frequently which adds eventListeners. I put in a trace statement to confirm the eventListener redundancy.

```
trace("*** already has eventListener", tempEventButton.hasEventListener("eventClicked"));
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `hasEventListener()` to ensure the eventListener only gets added to the object once? Provided the object only has 1 instance of the event type passed into a listener that calls the same function, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MartynShutt - thanks. Yes, I will likely do that but I am trying to diagnose some odd behavior and trying to understand (with some certainty) if this might be a cause.

Comment: adding the exact same event listener has no effect and doesn't overwrite the first added listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Actionscript 3.0 reference on the [Event Dispatcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) class:

> Keep in mind that after the listener is registered, subsequent calls
>   to addEventListener() with a different type or useCapture value result
>   in the creation of a separate listener registration.

This implies that, providing you do not register the same listener (the function passed to `addEventListener`)  with a different type or useCapture, a new eventListener wouldn't be created.

The question is whether or not this is a more expensive check for Event Dispatcher to perform than performing the check to ensure the `addEventListener()` for this event is only called once. Rather than call `hasEventListener()` to perform this check, you could flag that the listener has already been added in a `Boolean`, which wouldn't be a very expensive check to perform.

Comment: thanks. Yeah, I'll have to think about whether or not to add a check. I'm trying not to mess with the legacy code too much (many repetitive, redundant calls, etc) but that may take longer than just rewriting.

Comment: @TOMATO - Yes, it would depend on your particular situation and how often the code attempts to re-add the same listenerEvent, and whether or not it has any significant performance impact. At least it doesn't have any compounding effect, considering the listener is only added the once.